# How to check if an object is nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, object, null

I made a Class that has several NSStrings as properties. If I have an object of this class, then how can I know if the object is nil (i.e. all the NSString properties are nil).

My class looks like this

```
//  MyClass.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding> {
 NSString *string1;
 NSString *string2;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string2;

@end
```

I'm checking it like this and it doesn't work

```
if (SecondViewController.myObject==nil) {
 NSLog(@"the object is empty");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Is you object nil but code does not get executed? Try to run your program in debug mode to see what is myObject's actual value is.

Comment: What I mean is that the initialized object is seen as non-nil, even though I haven't given the strings in the object any value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I have an object of this class, then how can I know if the object is nil (i.e. all the NSString properties are nil).

An object is not nil just because all its properties are nil.  However, if you do want to know if both the string properties of your object are nil, this will do the trick:

```
-(BOOL) bothStringsAreNil
{
    return [self string1] == nil && [self string2] == nil;
}
```

Note: I'm in the camp that doesn't like to treat pointers as booleans i.e. I prefer the above to

```
-(BOOL) bothStringsAreNil
{
    return ![self string1]  && ![self string2];
}
```

which is functionally identical.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!obj)  
   // obj = nil

if (!obj.property)
   // property = nil
```

To check if all properties are nil I think it would better to create a special method in your class for that.

Comment: If (!obj) doesn't work on my class. I think it only works on NS classes

Comment: if () checks whether value is false(0) or true(!=0) so it should work on any type - number, c-pointer, obj-c object... May be the object you check is just not initialized?

Comment: @Vladimir: Instance variables are automatically set to *null / nil*.

Comment: @awakeFromNib: This answer looks correct, I think your using it in a wrong way. Can you show us the code where you are trying to check for *nil*?

Comment: @George, instances - YES, but one of the reasons  check mail fail on a custom object (not iVar) is is it is not initialized - awakeFromNib  wrote that  If (!obj) does not work