# How to check if object is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

We get a crash report via crushlytics for some of our users.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: event_id)

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) eventToJsonDict:(FTEvent*) event And:(NSDateFormatter*)dateFormatter
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictEvents = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dictEvents setObject:[event eventId] forKey:@"event_id"];
...
}
```

Its happening above. It seems the event object is somehow nil.

The strange part is, that I check for it if the object is nil or not before calling the method.

```
if ([arr count] > 0) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    for (FTEvent *event in arr) {
        if (event) {
            [jsonEvents addObject:[self eventToJsonDict:event And:dateFormatter]];
        }
    }    
}
```

Is it enough checking via `if (event)` if event is nil or not?

It seems there is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750079/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nil). However it doesn't really answer my question. I have done the same thing as the second answer.

Comment: You need to check `[event eventId]` before adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: [dictEvents setInteger:[event eventId] forKey:@"event_id"];

Comment: may be data type issue

Comment: @Desdenova ah now I understand. The instance itself isn't nil.  Its the property that is nil. Hence I need to check also for `if [event eventId]` before calling the method, correct?